# angular2 is not able to find common directive

Tags: angular

I am new to angular2.

```
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES,NgForm} from 'angular2/common';
```

The error i am getting is:

> system.src.js:1063 GET http://127.0.0.1:9090/src/angular2/common 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What is your System.js configuration, and what angular2 files you load in index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this configuration in the head of my HTML page, it works for me:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry